# Reduce memory consumption of of large dictionary of floats in python

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, memory, casting

I have a dictionary that is a collection of long numeric float lists.  My code needs to remain this way, but is there a way to reduce the memory of this with only using out of the box python?  My floats only need to be about 4 digits but many have more decimal places?  Can those be down cast?  Also I recently had to move to 64 bit and that also increased memory usage.  Is there a way to return to close to the 32 bit memory usage and still use 64 bit python?

The code is a 10 month project so I can't easily just convert everything to a dataframe so I am really scrambling for anything to reduce the size of this dictionary of lists full of floats.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe look at [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) module?

Comment: If there is a substantial quantity of duplicate float values, you could save some space by interning them (in much the same way as the `intern()` function deduplicates strings).

Comment: The size of a float depends on the total number of significant digits you need (before and after the decimal combined), not really the maximum magnitude.

Comment: But if single-precision floats are adequate for your needs I agree with the recommendation to use `array`. It allows you to declare an array of `float` rather than `double`.

Comment: I think the array module and or intern might help.  To be honest, I was hoping there was a lazy way of setting all floats to like float 16 in python.  As I am running out of time for the project, but I think those are great starting points. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need all of your arrays in memory at once, you could use the [shelve module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html).  Though you'd need to make sure that performance doesn't take too big of a hit.

Comment: If you're using `shelve` or some other method to ensure you don't have to hold the whole thing in memory at once, manual garbage collection using `gc.collect()` can be really useful. I've had experiences in the past where I was using persistent data structures and my programme ground to a halt anyway because automatic garbage collection wasn't happening regularly enough.

Comment: See [*Numpy*](https://numpy.org/), to be able to perform fast computations on the arrays/lists and to control the size of the float (32-bit vs 64-bit). Numpy even support 16-bit floats.